Understanding 最後に咥えて人の煙で吸った気になりたいから
He got diagnosed with lung cancer and he is not allowed to smoke anymore. He meets up with his smoking buddy for the last time.

I am not sure what he meant by 最後に咥えて人の煙で吸った気になりたいから. He will put a cigarette in his mouth (without lighting it up) and experience second-hand smoking? If that's case, then why it is not written as 人の煙を吸う気になりたい? I am confused by the use of particle で and past tense 吸った.


This で is a method/means marker. 煙 is not the object of 吸う but the method of how he can (吸った)気になる.
～する気になる means "to feel like doing something", but ～した気になる means "to feel as if one has done something" or "to pretend one did something". Both have to be memorized as set expressions.


人の煙で吸った気になりたいから。
I want to feel like I've smoked by using someone else's smoke.

